# Highchart y axis min interval

Tags: javascript, highcharts, intervals

i would like to show a positive, negative spline chart with different intervals

let say 
positive 0 to 50 and the interval has to increment by 5 
negative 0 to 1000 the interval has to increment by 100

is there any way i can do this in Highcharts

here is the Series im trying to display

```
 series: [{
            id: 'error1',
            name: 'Errors One',
            color:'red',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
        }, {
            id: 'ErrorsOne',
            color: 'red',
            data: [-222, -234, -123, -189, -289],
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            id:'error2',
            name: 'Errors Two',
            color:'blue',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
        }, {
            id:'ErrorsTwo',
            color:'blue',
            data: [-300, -245, -122, -245, -166],
            showInLegend: false
        }]
```

here is the url for [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psramkumar/8aEs2/)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use tickPostions or tickPositioner

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner